# Update QGIS on Mac OS X

Tags: qgis, installation, mac, update

I would like to update QGIS from 2.2 to 2.4 on Mac OS X (10.8) but I cannot find how to do so.

Do I have to uninstall and re-install all from KyngChaos? If so, I would therefore lose the extensions I have added manually.

Nothing is really clear about this on the Net.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No problem, you only need to download  [QGIS 2.4](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) and install it.

1. the application (QGIS.app) is placed in /Applications/
2. the frameworks are in /Library/Frameworks/ (/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework for example)
3. the extensions are in /Users/you/.qgis2/python/plugins (hidden folder, /Users/me/.qgis2/python/plugins/tablemanager for example)
4. the Python modules are in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib for example)

You can upgrade 1) or 2) or 3) or 4) independently. (Mac Os X is an UNIX system)

If you want to keep the old 2.2 version, rename the application, QGIS_2.2.app, for example, otherwise QGIS.app is replaced by the new version.

Comment: That's great ! Many thanks for these explanations...